# deploy same plug with different version

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle

I have osgi project with couple plugins
one of the plugin called:

```
com.lilum.sr.util
```

and otheres plugin use this plugin

plugin:

> com.lilum.sr.serveA

```
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 com.lilum.sr.util="1.2.3"
```

> com.lilum.sr.serveB

```
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime,
     com.lilum.sr.util="1.2.5"
```

as you can see plugin **com.lilum.sr.serveA** use **com.lilum.sr.util** version 1.2.3

and plugin **com.lilum.sr.serveB** use **com.lilum.sr.util** version 1.2.5

and when i deploy them, both use **com.lilum.sr.util** highets version (1.2.5)
but i want to force **com.lilum.sr.serveA** to use **com.lilum.sr.util** (1.2.3)

there is any way to do it?

I also try to use range version ([1.2.3, 1.2.4))
but i get  error can't resolve com.lilum.sr.util_[1.2.3, 1.2.4)
it's seems osgi deploy only the highets version

Comment: What build/deploy technology are you using? Maven perhaps, and as a standalone app or WAR?

Answer (score 0):

In OSGI, the third segment of a version identifies a "service" or "patch" release. Only the first and second identify when the API has changed. Because of this, OSGI is probably treating your two bundles as equivalent in API and opting for the "better" of the two: the one with more patches applied to it.

You should update the major or minor version number to indicate that API modifications were made to your bundle, and it should then work properly. If you have no API changes but only implementation detail changes and all else is equivalent in your two bundles, then there should be no reason to use the one with the lower third segment.

See also https://wiki.eclipse.org/Version_Numbering

Also, if your bundle has metadata that requires it to be a system-singleton, you will not be able to have multiple in your OSGI runtime anyway.

Comment: i have no singleton on "com.lilum.sr.util" (i have singleton=true on com.lilum.sr.serveA ) and i try already to change minor version number but still same problem